# css3 Swing animation not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css, css-animations

The following CSS3 swing animation, doesn't work in IE.

Is there anything I can do to make this work?

```
.image{
    -moz-animation: 3s ease 0s normal none infinite swing;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 36%;
    -webkit-animation:swing 3s infinite ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 36%;
}

@-moz-keyframes swing{
    0%{-moz-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
    50%{-moz-transform:rotate(3deg)}
    100%{-moz-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
}

@-webkit-keyframes swing{
    0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
    50%{-webkit-transform:rotate(3deg)}
    100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
}
```

Live preview: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/K44U3/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this version, complete with all vendor prefixes:

```
.image {
    -webkit-animation: 3s ease 0s normal none infinite swing;
    -moz-animation: 3s ease 0s normal none infinite swing;
    -ms-animation: 3s ease 0s normal none infinite swing;
    -o-animation: 3s ease 0s normal none infinite swing;
    animation: 3s ease 0s normal none infinite swing;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 36%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 36%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 36%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 36%;
    transform-origin: 50% 36%;
}

@keyframes swing {
 0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
 }
 50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
    transform: rotate(3deg);
 }
 100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
 }

}

@-moz-keyframes swing {
 0% {
   -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
   transform: rotate(-3deg);
 }
 50% {
   -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
   transform: rotate(3deg);
 }
 100% {
   -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
   transform: rotate(-3deg);
 }

}

@-webkit-keyframes swing {
 0% {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
   transform: rotate(-3deg);
 }
 50% {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
   transform: rotate(3deg);
 }
 100% {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
   transform: rotate(-3deg);
 }

}

@-ms-keyframes swing {
 0% {
   -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
   transform: rotate(-3deg);
 }
 50% {
   -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
   transform: rotate(3deg);
 }
 100% {
   -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
   transform: rotate(-3deg);
 }

}

@-o-keyframes swing {
 0% {
   -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
   transform: rotate(-3deg);
 }
 50% {
   -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
   transform: rotate(3deg);
 }
 100% {
   -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
   transform: rotate(-3deg);
 }

}
```

Comment: Did not work either. Maybe It's the animation values IE doesn't recognize?

Comment: @Boris Got it - you cannot quote the keyframes identifier. Make it `swing`, not `"swing"`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Works perfectly in jsFiddle. But when I added the exact same code to my project. It doesn't work. **Take a [look](http://pad.ample.pw/pitchwise/)**.

Comment: Something else seems to cause IE10 to choke on your stylesheet - exactly what is difficult for me to debug on your domain. Try removing everything unrelated to the animation from your stylesheet until it works again, then slowly add things back until you figure out what breaks it.

Comment: I bet it's because the width and heigh of the div are set to 100%. In jsFiddle, the width and height are fixed and it works perfectly. Though I can't use fixed values, because when you resize the browser window, the images shrink as well. Anyway, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I updated your Fiddle to have a correct stylesheet. http://jsfiddle.net/docluv/K44U3/4/. I have to recommend using Visual Studio and Web Essentials, it will save your butt when it comes to vendor specifics, missing rules, etc. http://vswebessentials.com/ http://www.asp.net/get-started

Answer (score 0):

What version of IE? CSS3 animations are supported by version 10 or above.
http://caniuse.com/css-animation

**Edit:**
And you missed non-vendor specific declaration

```
.image{
    animation: 3s ease 0s normal none infinite swing;
    transform-origin: 50% 36%;
}

@keyframes swing{
    0%{transform:rotate(-3deg)}
    50%{transform:rotate(3deg)}
    100%{transform:rotate(-3deg)}
}
```